# Adding values from 2 different files

Tags: java, methods, printwriter

In my program I scan 2 files, the 1st file I get the hours and the payRate to calculate each individual employees base pay, the 2nd file gets the sales of each employee to calculate the commissions for that week.

Then I combine the results in one file, but I need to add the commission and the base pay for each employee to get the weekly grosspay for each employee. I'm at a lost here, I want to add each individual base pay with their respective commissions to get the weekly grosspay, also, I added social security number, Is there a way that I could do this with separate files or the same file scanning for numbers with the same identifier (in this case the same social security number) and add the corresponding values?[Two files (1) Salary_Hours  (2) Sales](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GB5CR.jpg)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Payroll_Sales {

private static Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File fileSalary = new File ("Salary.txt");
    File salaryFile = new File ("NewPrint.txt");
    PrintWriter salaryPrint = new PrintWriter (salaryFile);
    salaryPrint = getSalary (fileSalary, salaryFile);

    File fileSales = new File ("Sales.txt");
    FileWriter salesFile = new FileWriter ("NewPrint.txt", true);
    PrintWriter salesPrint = new PrintWriter (salesFile);
    salesPrint = getSales (fileSales, salesFile);
}
private static PrintWriter getSales(File fileSales, FileWriter salesFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
    PrintWriter salesPrint = new PrintWriter (salesFile);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (fileSales);
    String ssn;
    double sales = 0, commission=0, salesCommission=0;
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        ssn = scan.next();
        sales = scan.nextDouble();
        if (sales >= 10000) {
            commission = .15;
        }
        else if (sales >= 7500) {
            commission = .10;
        }
        else if (sales >= 4500) {
            commission = .07;
        }
        else {
            commission = .05;
        }
        salesCommission = commission*sales;
        salesPrint.printf("%11s  $ %,3.2f \n", ssn, salesCommission);
        System.out.printf("%11s  $ %,3.2f \n", ssn, salesCommission);
    }
    salesPrint.close();
    return salesPrint;
}
private static PrintWriter getSalary(File fileSalary, File salaryFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
    PrintWriter salaryPrint = new PrintWriter (salaryFile);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (fileSalary);
    String ssn;
    double salary = 0, hours=0, payRate=0;
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        ssn = scan.next();
        payRate = scan.nextDouble();
        hours = scan.nextDouble();
        salary = payRate * hours;
        salaryPrint.printf("%11s  $ %,3.2f \n", ssn, salary);
        System.out.printf("%11s  $ %,3.2f \n", ssn, salary);

    }
    System.out.println();
    salaryPrint.println();
    salaryPrint.close();
    return salaryPrint;
}
  }
```

[CombineFile_Salary and SalesCommissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJkJg.jpg)

Comment: General recommendation, start by defining the information you need.  You seem to need some kind of `Employee`, which I assume has some kind of identifier; some kind of `TimeSheet` and `PayRate`; and some kind of `Sale` object, which I assume contains information about the total of the sale.  From the files, you need to load the information into instances of these classes and from there combine the results, this is where been able to identify the employee is going to be important

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I tend to divide file or IO work into two steps.

1) Parse the input into a model

This could be an class representing your application with additional classes for different data types (Employee has a sales num, payrate, num hours etc)

2) Now that you have your model, introduce your business logic since you should have all the information you need since once parsing is done.

Note, depending on the size of your input, the amount of memory needed will scale proportionately so if the size of these files is very large, I recommend you introduce a database or something as that will be a lot easier to manage (**I don't expect this will be necessary based on your initial code**)

The pseduo code would look something like this

```
public static <ModelClass> parseInput(file1, file2){
//Read through the files and instantiate your model data
//This should cover any information you need in your business logic
//(Meaning you should be able to close the files and not open them again
}

public <ModelClass> calculatePay(<ModelClass> model){
//Use your data structure to compute what you want to compute
//Return modified instance of the model
}
```

*The reason I suggest this* is because I have spent too much time in the past trying to do it all at once (parsing data from a file and computing logic). It's not always the right answer, but that's what refactoring is for!